# postgres: SQL and streaks?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to figure out the quickest way of populating the last column in this table, the `streak` column which stores the run of result values (either `win` or `loss`).

```
 game_date  | team    | result | streak 
------------+---------+--------+--------
 2017-10-05 | ABC     | win    | 1
 2017-10-07 | ABC     | win    | 2
 2017-10-11 | ABC     | loss   | 1
 2017-10-14 | ABC     | win    | 1
 2017-10-15 | ABC     | win    | 2
 2017-10-18 | ABC     | win    | 3
 2017-10-21 | ABC     | win    | 4
 2017-10-23 | ABC     | loss   | 1
 2017-10-24 | ABC     | win    | 1
 2017-10-26 | ABC     | win    | 2
 2017-10-28 | ABC     | win    | 3
 2017-10-30 | ABC     | loss   | 1
 2017-11-02 | ABC     | win    | 1
 2017-11-04 | ABC     | loss   | 1
 2017-11-07 | ABC     | win    | 1
 2017-11-09 | ABC     | loss   | 1
 2017-11-12 | ABC     | loss   | 1
 2017-11-14 | ABC     | loss   | 2
 2017-11-16 | ABC     | loss   | 3
 2017-11-18 | ABC     | win    | 1
 2017-11-19 | ABC     | loss   | 1
 2017-11-22 | ABC     | loss   | 2
 2017-11-24 | ABC     | loss   | 3
 2017-11-25 | ABC     | win    | 1
 2017-11-28 | ABC     | win    | 2
 2017-11-30 | ABC     | win    | 3
 2017-12-01 | ABC     | win    | 4
(27 rows)
```

As you see, `streak` should reset to 1 when the prior result is null, or different, otherwise increment by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can identifies the sequences of wins and losses by using the difference of `row_numbers()` to identify the "islands" of result values.  The rest is just a final application o `row_number()`:

```
select g.*,
       row_number() over (partition by seqnum - seqnum_r, result order by game_date) as streak
from (select g.*,
             row_number() over (order by game_date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by result order by game_date) as seqnum_r
      from games g
     ) g
```